# What triggers Windows Defender's to activate

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I created a C programme to create an EXE file with 1 virus signature, which I got it from this list: http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/downloads/antivirus/antivirus/virussignatures.strings

The problem is that only some of the signatures are detected, and they are usually very long.

I decided to test the undetected signatures with free (Absolutely no in-app purchases) antivirus. All of the signatures were detected.

So there must be something else that triggers it. Right?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound To find out why Windows Defender would not detect the signatures I created

Comment: Windows Defender can only detect malicious files it has a signature for.  It does not have behavior based detection.